# Running elisp within an orgmode code block

Tags: org-mode, org-babel, window

Consider the following elisp source code within a `.org` file:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC elisp :results silent
(delete-other-windows)
(split-window-right)
(switch-to-buffer-other-window '"*Python*")
#+END_SRC
```

This code is meant to delete all other windows, create a new window to the right (I work with 2 windows side by side), and then switch to that window and open an already running Python interpreter there.

It works if I go line by line and `C-x C-e` to evaluate the elisp code.
However, running the code block via `C-c C-c` in org mode does not produce the desired effect.

**Question:** Is it possible to modify that code block so that running it with `C-c C-c` produces the desired effect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following lisp code defines the new emacs-lisp source block parameter `:keep-windows`.
You can modify the window configuration through the source block if you set this parameter to `t`.

You can put the source code in your [init file](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Init-File.html).

It replaces `save-window-excursion` in `org-babel-execute:emacs-lisp` by a newly defined macro
`save-window-excursion-if`. The new macro needs a predicate as new first argument. The window configuration is only stored if that predicate is non-nil.
That is where the new source block parameter `:keep-windows` is tested.

The function `replace-in-fundef` below needs access to the source file `ob-emacs-lisp.el`.

```el
(require 'ob-emacs-lisp)
(defun transform-tree (tree trafo)
  "Transform TREE by TRAFO."
  (let ((next tree))
    (while next
      (let ((this next))
    (setq next (cdr next))
    (if (consp (car this))
        (transform-tree (car this) trafo)
      (funcall trafo this)))))
  tree)

(defun replace-in-fundef (fun sym &rest replacement)
  "In function FUN perform REPLACEMENT."
  (setq fun (or
         (condition-case err
         (let* ((pos (find-function-noselect fun t))
            (buf (car pos))
            (pt (cdr pos)))
           (with-current-buffer buf
             (save-excursion
               (goto-char pt)
               (read buf))))
         (error nil))
         (and (symbolp fun) (symbol-function fun))
         fun))
  (transform-tree fun
   (lambda (this)
     (when (eq (car this) sym)
       (let ((copy-repl (cl-copy-list replacement)))
     (setcdr (last copy-repl) (cdr this))
     (setcdr this (cdr copy-repl))
     (setcar this (car copy-repl)))))))

(defmacro save-window-excursion-if (pred &rest body)
  "Act like `save-window-excursion' if PRED is non-nil."
  (declare (indent 1) (debug t))
  (let ((c (make-symbol "wconfig")))
    `(let ((,c (and ,pred (current-window-configuration))))
       (unwind-protect (progn ,@body)
         (when ,c (set-window-configuration ,c))))))

(advice-remove 'org-babel-execute:emacs-lisp #'ad-org-babel-execute:emacs-lisp)
;; make sure we have access to the source code of `org-babel-execute:emacs-lisp'
(find-function-noselect 'org-babel-execute:emacs-lisp t)
;; (defun ad-org-babel-execute:emacs-lisp ...):
(eval (replace-in-fundef 'org-babel-execute:emacs-lisp 'org-babel-execute:emacs-lisp 'ad-org-babel-execute:emacs-lisp))
;; Use `save-window-excursion-if' in `ad-org-babel-execute:emacs-lisp':
(declare-function 'ad-org-babel-execute:emacs-lisp " ")
(eval (replace-in-fundef 'ad-org-babel-execute:emacs-lisp
             'save-window-excursion 'save-window-excursion-if '(null (member (cdr (assoc :keep-windows params)) '("yes" "t")))))
;; Replace `org-babel-execute:emacs-lisp':
(advice-add 'org-babel-execute:emacs-lisp :override #'ad-org-babel-execute:emacs-lisp)
```

Your example source block can be augmented with `:keep-windows` as follows:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC elisp :results silent :keep-windows t
(delete-other-windows)
(split-window-right)
(switch-to-buffer-other-window '"*Python*")
#+END_SRC
```

Some details about the source code:

We want to replace `save-window-excursion` in `org-babel-execute:emacs-lisp`. `save-window-excursion` is a macro. That means we need the source code to replace the macro before its expansion.
We look `org-babel-execute:emacs-lisp` up with `find-function` and read it through the elisp reader.
The function definition can be interpreted as a tree constructed from lisp-lists (if the function is not byte-compiled).
Modifying that definition is a tree-transformation.

Comment: Wow, this is amazing. Works flawlessly. Thank you! In terms of understanding your code, any advice? I'm fairly new to elisp (haven't finished the tutorial yet).

Comment: @GuilhermeSalomé I added some short overview about the source code. Nevertheless you will need some elisp basics to understand the code. Maybe [the intro](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eintr/index.html#Top) and the [doc](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/elisp.html) help.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure the window-modifying behavior you want is not supported.  When you press `C-c C-c` on the source block it ultimately calls `org-babel-execute:emacs-lisp`, and that function wraps everything in a `save-window-excursion` form.

Are you just trying to easily reset your windows if they get out of alignment?  Consider defining your own function like

```
(defun my-window-fixup ()
  (interactive)
  (delete-other-windows)
  (split-window-right)
  (switch-to-buffer-other-window "*Python*"))
```

and bind `my-window-fixup` to a key in the org-mode-map with something like

```
(define-key org-mode-map (kbd "C-c f") #'my-window-fixup)
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I'm trying to understand how to produce something akin to a Jupyter notebook for Python but in orgmode. And these commands were just a quick way to open the Python interpreter side by side with my org buffer.

Comment: Oh!  Have you checked out [ob-ipython](https://github.com/gregsexton/ob-ipython) or [EIN](https://github.com/millejoh/emacs-ipython-notebook) (specifically the ob-ein part)?

Comment: Tiny self-promotion … I found ob-ipython too slow and EIN too complicated, so I wrote my own replacement [jupyter-mode](https://github.com/tmurph/jupyter-mode).  It’s still very much a WIP, though

Comment: I have checked EIN, but somehow I couldn't find it on MELPA. I am not sure if I want to dive into these notebooks right now, since orgmode seems capable of delivering similar results in a simpler fashion. Thanks for sharing your work, I'll check it out too!

Comment: Oh I gotcha.  Looking to use Org as a replacement for Jupyter?  Makes sense.  Be sure to check out the `:session` header argument for your Python blocks.  Also, `C-c C-v C-z` (`org-babel-switch-to-session`) should switch to the Python interpreter buffer from a Python source block.

Comment: I'm using `:session`. The good thing about it is that after opening the Python interpreter, I can open a `.py` file and use the same interpreter with Elpy. Thanks for pointing out that shortcut, that's very helpful! Thanks for your help! :D