# org-mode call occur not function

Tags: org-mode, occur

Since I need to search some pattern frequently, I wish to write some code there then execute it in org-mode. for example:

```
#+begin_src elisp :results output
(defun myoccur (arg)
  (occur (s-replace " " "\\|" arg))
)
(myoccur "cat dog mouse")
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:

this is a dog.
this is a cat.
this is a mouse.
this is a pig.
```

If I do C-c C-c, one *Occur* buffer will be generated but it do not popup to split the screen, I have to switch to that buffer to view the result.

How can I make this code popup the *Occur* buffer after C-c C-c command?

Comment: Are you set on having this in an org code block and running it that way? Or would it be acceptable to create your own command to do this?

Comment: I prefer to do it in org file since it's easy to modify! if create my own command, it works fine.

Comment: You know that emacs can also modify regular elisp files and you can evaluate a sexp with `C-x C-e`? And that you can put elisp into (or old it from) your init file to define functions at startup? But I guess this means that you are set on having this in org mode.

Comment: You have to take control of the windows split, and Org Mode does not make it easy.  But there is a way: [Running elisp within an orgmode code block](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/42096/running-elisp-within-an-orgmode-code-block).